# Как настроить VS code для удобной навигации по вкладкам. По умолчанию они скрыт если не влазят на экран?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Там можно воспользоваться вот этим меню но это не удобно, может есть горячие клавиши или можно как то добавить навигацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `CTRL+PageDown` и `CTRL+PageUp`?

Comment: `CTRL+P` для того чтобы открыть выпадающий список со всеми вкладками (и файлами), в выпадающем списке можно произвести поиск

Answer (score 2):

для навигации по вкладкам можно использовать `ctrl+tab` и `ctrl+shift+tab`.

Comment: супер коротко...

Answer (score 2):

Можно пользоваться `CTRL+PageDown` (для следующей вкладки), и `CTRL+PageUp` для предыдущей вкладки.

А вообще, можно включить `Открытые редакторы`,

[image: Скриншот 1]

Нужно, чтобы была включена галочка `Открытые редакторы`. И тогда можно будет удобно пользоваться так:

[image: Скриншот 2]